# postgres ERROR: relation "routine_privileges" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am trying to put together a query to find unused indexes in a postgres database:

```
SELECT indexrelname, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)), idx_scan 
FROM pg_stat_all_indexes 
WHERE idx_scan=0 
    AND indexrelname NOT LIKE 'pg_toast_%';
```

The above seems to work all right, but I want to concentrate on the big indexes, so I added an extra condition:

```
SELECT indexrelname, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)), idx_scan 
FROM pg_stat_all_indexes 
WHERE idx_scan=0 
    AND indexrelname NOT LIKE 'pg_toast_%' 
    AND pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)) > 1000000 ;
```

Which resulted in

```
ERROR:  relation "routine_privileges" does not exist
```

Could someone tell me why the second query is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname))` makes no sense at all. `pg_relation_size(indexrelname)` is completely enough. `quote_ident` is intended when you create dynamic SQL. Remove it and see if that get's rid of the error.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should also exclude unique indexes from your query. They might be "unused" but they are still important

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I remove quote_ident (`SELECT indexrelname, pg_relation_size(indexrelname) as size FROM pg_stat_all_indexes`), then the error is: `ERROR:  function pg_relation_size(name) does not exist`. `SELECT indexrelname, pg_relation_size(indexrelname::text) as size FROM pg_stat_all_indexes;` works, I will look into that

Comment: `indexrelname::text` is the better choice, yes. I am not sure, but it might be that `pg_stat_all_indexes` returns table names where your current user has no access and that's the reason for the error. Do you still get the error if you use `pg_stat_user_indexes` instead of `all_indexes`?

Comment: I am logged in as postgres user, who is the most super admin of all. Is it possible, that it does not have access to something? Or could this be a database error? How to detect the latter?